# Solve Underdetermined System of Equations for Sparse Solution

Tags: linear-algebra, eigen

- A, C are m x n rectangular matrix.
- B is a n x n square matrix.
- B is not symmetric.
- B, C are known
- AB = C.
- B is singular.

I could use the moore-penrose inverse of B to get A = CB<sup>+</sup>.

But that seems to make A have many non-zero elements.

If I want an A (among all possible solutions) that is quite sparse, what solvers can I try?

Should I use BDCSVD, as in [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__LeastSquares.html)?

Thanks.

Comment: Somehow colPivHouseholderQr seems to give a sparse answer for my case, which is a least square problem.

Comment: `bdcSvd(ComputeThinU | ComputeThinV).` doesn't give sparse solution, but it is much more accurate. `colPivHouseholderQr` can have about 1% error in the entries of A.

Comment: I vaguely remember reading that QR is good for least square. Don't remember the reason. Does it try to make the columns of the solution orthogonal?

Comment: SVD-based solver will give you the minimal L2-norm solution (each column of A) which is, by nature the safest to compute because the closest to 0. For a sparse solution, you would ideally like to seek for the minimal L1-norm solution, but that's likely more involved.

Comment: Maybe you could try to 1) compute the minimal-L2-norm solution A2 using SVD, 2) solve a second time by enforcing the n-r (with r the rank of B as given by the previous SVD decomp.) smallest coefficients of each column of A2 to be zero (so you solve for one column at a time). This should work reasonably, but this will be significantly more costly.

Comment: oh, I did not paid attention that you are solving on the left, so replace _column_ by _row_ in what I said.

Answer (score 0):

Under-determined systems usually have *infinite* number of solutions. Unless you impose some additional conditions (restrictions), in form of additional equation(s), you won't obtain a single numerical solution.

Comment: I want to get any one of the most (or nearly most) sparse solutions.

Comment: The term "sparse" is used for describing matrices, not solutions. A solution of a system of linear equations is just a vector, and its sparsity (or otherwise) is not related to the fact whether the matrix of the system is sparse or not. You would probably find more information from literature, or just ask questions at another forum devoted to sparse matrices, where discussions are encouraged, for example from  https://comecau.blogspot.com/2018_09_05_archive.html

Comment: see http://math.mit.edu/~liewang/OMP.pdf or http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_omp.html

Comment: Sometimes it takes 50+ years for one idea to spread from one field to another field ... I only care about meaning instead of terms now.

Comment: I think that the problem the you formulated from the very beginning, can be solved using a procedure that is presented on the following page: http://comecau.blogspot.com/2018_10_05_archive.html  ; please feel free to leave a comment there (a discussion regarding the references that you provided is also welcome).

Comment: I think sparse matrix usually mean a small L1 norm instead of a small L2 norm. See: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45643/why-l1-norm-for-sparse-models At a quick glance, the method at the blog is about finding a solution with a small L2 norm instead of L1 norm, because the last few sentences talked about least square instead of lasso ...

Comment: The term "sparse matrix" means that it contains a significant number of zeros, not the way the matrix was obtained. In my opinion, your problem can be solved by development of a customised software program, with clearly defined goals and conditions.

Comment: Well. I agree with your definition of sparse matrix. I think you understand what I want (the problem). However, the method at the blog uses least square, which minimizes the L2 norm instead of L1 norm. Minimizing L1 norm leads to sparsity. Minimizing L2 norm usually does not yield sparse matrix, as in Moore-Penrose inverse. At a quick glance, I am not sure if the method can produce a solution with as many zero entries as possible. Wikipedia for Moore-Penrose describes connection with least square.  L1 & sparsity: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45643/why-l1-norm-for-sparse-models

Comment: The method at the blog for possibility one might work. But I was thinking about the following. Gaussian elimination/pivoting removes an equation if it is linearly dependent with another equation. What if the remaining independent equations still permits some variables to be zero? For example, suppose the linear system consists of a single equation: x + y = 5. In this case, y can still be zero. Multiple `a` vectors can still satisfy the system of linear equations, even after setting alpha vector to zero. Some of the possible `a` vectors are more sparse than others.

Comment: Well, as I said, it is a separate R&D project, requiring customised software development.

Comment: I mean currently the math at the blog post is not enough to solve possibility one. SVD would not work well for possibility two in my opinion. Quite a lot of people were working on problems about sparse signals for various applications, including summary of big data and compressed sensing for electronics and astronomy. If you find a new method, they might be interested.